# Can python multiprocessing results be accessed/saved before deserializing/unpickling?

Tags: python, serialization, multiprocessing, pickle

I am using the Python `multiprocessing` package to run several iterations of a simulation in parallel.

`pool = multiprocessing.Pool()`

`result = pool.map(runSimulation, args)`

Each simulation returns a large dictionary of data. Given the large number of iterations I have to run, the final output contained in `result` is huge. Ideally, I'd pickle such a large data file before saving it. However, my understanding of the `multiprocessing` module is that it consists of an `outque` which holds the serialized return values of each task. Later, a bound method called `_result_handler` deserializes these values, and returns them to `pool.map()`.

My question is this: can I access and save the serialized version of these results before it is deserialized by `_result_handler`, thus avoiding multiple rounds of serializing/deserializing?

Comment: you can do whatever you like with the values before you return them from the task function

Comment: @Anentropic Do you mean serialize it before the return? So that the extra (de)serialization isn't avoided but presumably is much more efficient?

Comment: sorry I think I misunderstood, OP wants to get the collated serialized result before it is deserialized

Comment: @Anentropic If I understand you, you are suggesting that modify ```runSimulation``` to pickle the results and store them away before the returning anything to ```pool.map()```. Can multiple parallel processes access and use the same pickle file?

Comment: no, I think if you were to do that then you should have lots of pickle files with the individual results and then would need some other code to load those and reconstruct the full result

Comment: @KellyBundy No, I wanted to access the serialized version of the results that ```multiprocessing``` creates, therefore explicitly avoiding the deserialization that ```_result_handler``` performs. I don't want to have to re-serialize the just-deserialized results...

Comment: @Anentropic, yeah, that's what I figured too... I'd definitely like to avoid 1000+ pickle files in my output folder!

Comment: use a temp folder :)

Comment: @VRbandname Yes, I understand that. Seems dangerous, though, as you're relying on the format currently used by `multiprocessing`'s serialization. My point is that if you serialize the dictionary *before* you return, `multiprocessing` serializes and deserializes `bytes`, which is presumably much more efficient. Quite possibly it's even insignificant.

Comment: @KellyBundy Hmm, makes sense. Lemme give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you can avoid it, you then depend on the serialization format currently used by `multiprocessing`. You could instead serialize your dictionary yourself *before* returning it (or rather its serialized version then). Then the transfer serializes and deserializes `bytes` instead of a dictionary with lots of objects, which is much more efficient.

Test results with a dict of a million items, comparing your current way of (re)serializing *after* the transfer versus serializing *before* the transfer. The latter is over three times faster (and probably uses a lot less memory, too), and barely takes longer than just serializing the dictionary:

```
1185 ms  after
 351 ms  before
 337 ms  just_pickle
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHdSgMxEIXv8xRzU5rIUlzWCynskxRZ9ifR1OaHyeRCxGdfk00sVsVcBIY535yTiX@jF2e7R4/rqtAZIG2kJtDGO6RasVp5Pb9eJGOLVEA42qAkcjedxZFBOigpoq2qw8WNS@C1WKLxYZOKgp9joKE0@Z94IZaZKjAqSmb/SK@BMlOhSSqHPw2uwl9OmZoJengPhFyLI2hIA9KtLSTqWfL2fjvigzGP2hK/eW0NKaDvb9fwFSRb5Ikq2jkPPW1EU4M239fyBHfQleA5UvkJnsEGbDSTxL4VW7sE2e8eFjAB9rADTgluZSeazekwDHY0chgEW9dP)):

```
from timeit import timeit
import pickle

def transfer(obj):
    return pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(obj))

def just_pickle():
    return pickle.dumps(dct)

def after():
    return pickle.dumps(transfer(dct))

def before():
    return transfer(pickle.dumps(dct))

dct = {str(i): i for i in range(1000000)}

print(pickle.loads(after()) == pickle.loads(before()))

for func in [after, before, just_pickle] * 3:
    t = timeit(func, number=1)
    print('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
```

Comment: If I understand your benchmark correctly, `before` represents the case where the sub-process pickles the dictionary and then returns that pickled result (a `bytes` instance) back to the main process by serializing it and de-serializing it with pickle. But what you are missing is that the main process ends up with a pickled dictionary and cannot use this without now "un-pickling" it, which you are not including in your benchmark. Moreover a pickled dictionary that takes M bytes of storage takes N bytes of storage when you pickle again the serialized dictionary.  (more...)

Comment: I believe [this](https://ideone.com/qvH5am) is a more accurate benchmark. It still does not take into account that N >> M and moving more data between processes is an additional overhead not accounted for.

Comment: @Booboo No, that looks wrong. They said they want to save it. Why would you unpickle it instead? And N is only minimally larger than M, I had checked. And yes, actually transferring the data between processes adds more overhead, making the pickling+unpickling of the `bytes` even more negligible.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that the OP also needed the dictionary reconstituted. Then I believe that your approach is clearly the best that can be accomplished. See [this](https://ideone.com/w9AaTY) for a benchmark that incorporates  multiprocessing.

Comment: @Booboo With my test dictionary, M is 13,761,459 bytes and N is [just 9 bytes more](https://tio.run/##ZYtBCsJADEX3OUV2nYCI4kYKHkbaqQbbTEjjopSefQzqSv/iLx7v6eL3IqezWq08aTFH5e4xZoC@c7zgOrslphYZh2LxLGhXueV0PLxHG4CG@Mn2/XPSOUVLoH9YKVxj8TQ065glQLvbGvqBX1rrCw). About the other issue: If in their main process they *do* want both the pickled and the unpickled dictionary, then yes, I agree your benchmark is right. Still, my suggestion would replace one dict pickling with bytes pickling+unpickling. Or in other words, I'd have the necessary dict pickling+unpickling plus pretty small overhead.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see my [*second* benchmark](https://ideone.com/w9AaTY), which is for the case when there is no need to reconstitute the dictionary after the pickled dictionary is returned. In any event, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Booboo Yes, thanks. I had seen it. Good to have that, too.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I've accepted this answer as best. Though it doesn't quite give me what I want, it yields some good efficiencies. Thanks!